# Simulate TAB keypress event in Selenium RC

Tags: selenium, tabs, selenium-rc, keypress

I need to simulate a tab keypress in Selenium RC, using the Java API.

I do this after having entered some text using:

```
selenium.type(input, "mytext");
```

I've tried 3 alternatives to get the tab working:

```
selenium.keyPress(input, "\\9");
```

and:

```
selenium.focus(input);
selenium.keyPressNative("09");
```

and even:

```
selenium.getEval("var evt = window.document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');evt.initKeyEvent ('keypress', true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 9,0);window.document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].dispatchEvent(evt);")
```

The best I can get is a "tab space" to be inserted after my text so I end up with this in the input field:

```
"mytext    "
```

What I actually want is to tab to the next control. Any clues? Thanks!

(Note: I have to use tab and can not use focus or select to chose the element I want to go to, for various reasons, so no suggestions along these lines please!)

Answer (score 4):

```
selenium.keyPressNative(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB + "");
```

I don't use the Java API, but [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/d2a6909ab7e8b9ae#) from google groups suggests it is your solution.  I can't imagine that "9" is different from "09" in your question, but give it a try?

Comment: 09 or 9, makes not difference I'm afraid.

Comment: What happens if you don't focus first?  i.e. just tab through the form, then enter something at the end (I'm not saying this will solve your problem, just curious)

Comment: I found it necessary to focus and then tab to trigger a blur.

Answer (score 3):

Try the official TAB char: `\t` or `\u0009`

Comment: @Joel: Please update the question to mention it.  I don't see `\t` anywhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

Some functions may used Onblur. It will trigger the function when the field lose the key focus. here we can use fireEvent with "blur" or "focus" command as follows:
command: fireEvent
target: id=your_field_identification
value: blur

Reference: http://qaselenium.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-triger-tab-key-in-selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

Improvising Ryley's answer, we can use

```
selenium.keyDownNative(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB + "");
selenium.keyUpNative(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB + "");
```

I tried this method for VK_CONTROL in IE and it worked good.

Answer (score 0):

Use [typeKeys()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#typeKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

Quoting the above link:

Unlike the simple "type" command, which forces the specified value into the page directly, this command may or may not have any visible effect, even in cases where typing keys would normally have a visible effect. For example, if you use "typeKeys" on a form element, you may or may not see the results of what you typed in the field.

In some cases, you may need to use the simple "type" command to set the value of the field and then the "typeKeys" command to send the keystroke events corresponding to what you just typed.