# Selenium IDE:Is it possible to record keyboard strokes in the application?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Hi this is varaprasad damerakonda, Guys,i got a doubt that is it possible to record keyboards strokes, (example:TAB button in email process) using selenium IDE as record and playback tool?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can just use

```
selenium.type("field-id", "string to type")
```

but in the particular case of a TAB, it [seems it's more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140616/simulate-tab-keypress-event-in-selenium-rc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible

See code below

```
<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>//div/b[text()='Send']</td>
    <td>13</td>
</tr>
```

13 is for enter key, you can insert any key value there.

Comment: I don't get it, this looks like some manual stuff you have to type, not something that Selenium creates automatically while recording what you type.  If I have to create something like the above for every keystroke I need I am going to go crazy, because my web app relies almost exclusively on keystrokes to do *everything*.

Comment: Yes, selenium will not records such events (enter key, tab key etc.), we have to provide manual steps into scripts.But you can pass test as input that selenium IDE can record.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Answer to the qs how to Record the Enter Key Through Selenium IDE

```
<td>keyDown</td>

<td>id=txtFilterContentUnit</td>

<td>\13</td>
```

Its Working i tried that on Selenium IDE
here, 
id=your Text Box Name {replace txtFilterContentUnit with your text box name}

hope u can do it
-Abhijeet